# Laravel Collection query results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In a custom artisan command, I'm trying to access all of the members of a model (e.g. User) with `User::all()`.

Records exist in the database for this model but User::all() in the command just returns `"Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3308}"` instead of the actual results. Dumper does not show any item inside of the collection, just show how many items collection have

This seems to only happen within the command as I am able to pull the results using Tinker.

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Comment: What is the minor version of Laravel 5?  5.6?

Comment: Foreach on collection doesn't give results ?

Comment: @cherrysoft The version is 5.6.35

Comment: @DavidAuvray No, it seems like it's just returning the Collection class not the actual results for that model/query

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses Symfony's VarCloner class and in this class has `$maxItems` attribute which is defined 2500 as default. (`$maxItems` coming from parent class)

If you want to get more items you may override or extend `Illuminate/Support/Debug/Dumper.php` class

this is default

```
public function dump($value)
    {
        if (class_exists(CliDumper::class)) {
            $dumper = 'cli' === PHP_SAPI ? new CliDumper : new HtmlDumper;
            $dumper->dump((new VarCloner)->cloneVar($value));
        } else {
            var_dump($value);
        }
    }
```

But you can say that you want to dump more items;

```
public function dump($value)
{
    if (class_exists(CliDumper::class)) {
        $dumper = 'cli' === PHP_SAPI ? new CliDumper : new HtmlDumper;
        $cloner = new VarCloner;
        $cloner->setMaxItems(4000);
        $dumper->dump($cloner->cloneVar($value));
    } else {
        var_dump($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hassan, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, there are only 3 of these models created so it should not be hitting that upper limit. The ::all() method for example works fine in a normal Tinker session and returns these three instances. However, when run inside of the artisan command, it just returns the Collection class not the actual data.

Comment: @A.Rahm Ops, I thought it's about exceeding items limits. question wasn't clear and you updated my edit so..

Comment: @A.Rahm Can you check laravel.log file ? Is there any error log ?

Comment: There are no errors related to this. I did some more digging and I am able to access the members of the Collection using array syntax, the main issue now just seems to be printing out inside of the shell. Which is more of a convenience thing anyway. Thanks for your help!